# Calculating Sum in Excel for select values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in my sheet. The first column contains the numeric values (money) and the second column, adjacent to it, defines its status (paid or due).
Is there a formula I can set for a cell that calculates the sum of the values in the first column which has the status paid in the next row?

Comment: Use `SUMIF()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula like below to sum it. assuming your money column is `B1:B4` and `A1:A4` is your paid or due status,

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4,"paid")
```

[image: Sample results for the sum paid money]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Sumif()` function like below.

```
=SUMIF(B1:B4,"Paid",A1:A4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So an example of sumif() and countif():

[image]

Note that there is a difference in the references.