# Count sum for range

Tags: excel

I'm hoping you can help me, I tried to do this in the database but the data returned was wrong so I'm trying in Excel and my brain can't seem to work this out. Help would be most appreciated.

I'm trying to get the total call count for each Week, each Month and year (see table below) but can't work out the formula.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1UH6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWcPm.png)

Comment: How is the total call count calculated? It's the sum of what exactly?

Comment: Have you considered sumif() or sumifs() - there are examples on here or in the excel funtion help

Comment: See this, if it helps give it a vote :https://stackoverflow.com/a/56097279/4961700